# Why rxjs invoke immediately timer in 2304115513 milliseconds?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I set a timer in rxjs to 2304115513 in milliseconds.

But when I run the timer the subscribe function is invoke immediately.

Why? I was expect to invoke after pass 2304115513 milliseconds.

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-ufmslp?devtoolsheight=60&file=index.ts)

```
import './style.css';
console.clear();
import { of, map, Observable, timer } from 'rxjs';

timer(2304115513).subscribe((r) => {
  console.log('tick!');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`timer` calls `setTimeout`, and `setTimeout` uses a 32 bit signed integer in its implementation in most browsers. As a result, the maximum time you can do a timeout for is 2,147,483,647 milliseconds

See this page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout#maximum_delay_value

Comment: okay, but I need to display something after that milliseconds. you have any idea how I'll do that?

Comment: You need to display something after 26ish days? It's rare for webpages to be open for that long. But if you need it, then how about doing a timer for half that time, then when it goes off do another timer for half the time.

Comment: Or just run a timer every "x" minutes/hours and calculate how much time has passed since the timer started.